# Python Bs4 IF Statement with Print() function - 2 outcomes

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm playing with IF statements with Bs4.

**Desired outcome:**

- If the button class is present then the IF statement ends and the print() function prints ('This item is listed') so the script can continue running.
- If the button is not present then the IF statement ends, the print() function prints ('This item is not listed') and the script can jump to some different code further down.

The script runs with no errors, but I can't get it to display the correct print() functions depending on if the button class is present or not. Any ideas?

```
#look for the button class
def s_check():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    sQuery = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "listed-btn"})
    if sQuery:
        return
    else:
        print('This item is NOT listed.')
print('This item is listed')

driver.get(URL)
time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: You're never calling the function.

Comment: Shouldn't `print('This item is listed')` be in the `if` block? Since it's outside the function, it will always be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mostly having minor logic issues and a few position of code issues.

First, you never call the function.
Second, you need to switch the return and the 'This item is listed' print statement.
Third, as a better way to pause your program, use a bare input() rather than sleep.

```
#look for the button class
def s_check():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    sQuery = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "listed-btn"})
    if sQuery:
        # This is swaped
        print('This item is listed')
    else:
        print('This item is NOT listed.')

    # This is the other swap
    return

driver.get(URL)

# You never call your function. This line will actually make the function run now.
s_check()

# time.sleep(2)
# Commented out the line above to replace it, so that it will wait until you press any key.
input()
```